# Can I create a pandas Dataframe from two lists but for each element of the first list I append n rows as the elements od the second list?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I was looking at the pandas documentation but did not find the answer there. Lets say I have the following lists:

```
Dates = ['01-01-2020','02-01-2020','03-01-2020']
Names = ['John','Anthony','Martha']
```

What I want to do is a merging or joinning of the list so I get the following Dataframe:

```
Date            Names
'01-01-2020'    'John'
'01-01-2020'    'Anthony'
'01-01-2020'    'Martha'
'02-01-2020'    'John'
'02-01-2020'    'Anthony'
'02-01-2020'    'Martha'
'03-01-2020'    'John'
'03-01-2020'    'Anthony'
'03-01-2020'    'Martha'
```

This would, for each element of the second list, multiply the elements in the first list.
I looked at the join and merge methods but did not find the answer.
Is there a simple method for that

Tks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `itertools.product`?

Here is example code.

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

Dates = ['01-01-2020','02-01-2020','03-01-2020']
Names = ['John','Anthony','Martha']

df = pd.DataFrame(itertools.product(Dates, Names))
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `pd.MultiIndex.from_product`

```
df=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([Dates,Names],names=['Date','Name']).to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)
         Date     Name
0  01-01-2020     John
1  01-01-2020  Anthony
2  01-01-2020   Martha
3  02-01-2020     John
4  02-01-2020  Anthony
5  02-01-2020   Martha
6  03-01-2020     John
7  03-01-2020  Anthony
8  03-01-2020   Martha
```